# Java - Thread calculate more slowly

Tags: java, java-threads

I am trying to calculate faster my program. But using thread makes it more slowly. Here is the code that simplified:

In this array, trying to sum every digits.
For example: unit digits = 3 + 6

```
List<String> myArr = new ArrayList<String>();
myArr.add("123");
myArr.add("456");
```

When calculate like this:

```
/* NORMAL USE */ 

long startTime1 = System.nanoTime();

int units=0; int tens=0; int hundreds=0;

for(int i=0; i < myArr.size(); i++) {
    units += Character.getNumericValue(myArr.get(i).charAt(2));
    tens += Character.getNumericValue(myArr.get(i).charAt(1));
    hundreds += Character.getNumericValue(myArr.get(i).charAt(0));
}

long endTime1 = System.nanoTime();
double estimatedTime1 = (endTime1 - startTime1)/1000000.0;

System.out.println(estimatedTime1 + " milliseconds");
```

Output:

```
0.0285 milliseconds
```

When calculate using Thread:

```
/* USING THREAD */ 

ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);

long startTime2 = System.nanoTime();

pool.execute(new UnitsDigit(myArr));
pool.execute(new TensDigit(myArr));
pool.execute(new HundredsDigit(myArr));

pool.shutdown();

long endTime2 = System.nanoTime();
double estimatedTime2 = (endTime2 - startTime2)/1000000.0;

System.out.println(estimatedTime2 + " milliseconds");
```

Output:

```
2.5015 milliseconds
```

Which part i am doing wrong? Thread should be faster.

Comment: You've missed out `awaitTermination` and you don't seem to be doing anything with the results. **2.5 milliseconds is not long.** Probably more to do with start up time. You are doing much more work. Both in overhead, and within the loop itself (the real work is in accessing non-consecutive memory, not doing integer addition).

Comment: I simplified the code to make more clear.  Added `awaitTermination` but it seems not about it. Actually just tried to use about 5,000 numbers, thats fine. I mean thread is faster, as you said 2.5 milliseconds is not long. Is everyhing about data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A typical newbie misconception: using multiple threads doesn't necessarily lead to faster execution!

Threads are in the end managed by the underlying operating system. Creating such threads comes therefore with a certain amount of overhead! Therefore using multiple threads makes sense only when the corresponding "tasks" have a certain duration. Beyond that, you also need a CPU able to run all the threads in parallel, otherwise you again lose against doing that computational work using a single thread.

In other words: throwing multiple threads on a simple computation that only needs "relatively few" milli or nanoseconds to complete achieves slower execution times!

Finally: the real benefit of multiple threads comes into existence when your threads spend a significant time waiting for something to happen (like doing file io).

So: when you intend to do meaningful experiments with one thread versus many, you have to incorporate such details when defining your setup.

Comment: Its actually a homework but however I was thinking that Threads works faster for every cases. As far as I understood, before using Threads, asking to "how much it helps to speed" will be better. Thanks a lot!